# Java Swing application window disappears when moved to another screen/desktop/display on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, swing

My Java Swing application window disappears whenever I drag it with the mouse from one monitor to another. It is visible while I drag it, but it disappears immediately when I release the mouse button. I would rather that the window didn't disappear. Why does it disappear?

When I activate Mission Control, the Swing Window appears at the bottom of the desktop where I dragged it. Deactivating Mission Control causes it to slide off the bottom of the screen.

It doesn't matter which Java Swing application I run. For those who want the code, here's a simple Java Swing application that exhibits the behavior I'm describing, enjoy:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class SimpleSwing {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
                    contentPane.add(new JLabel("Hello World!"));
                    frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

My environment is Oracle Java JDK (latest as of this writing) on Mac OS X Yosemite (latest as of this writing):

```
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)

OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.2 (14C1510)
Darwin Kernel Version 14.1.0
```

Comment: Does the second monitor have a large y offset?  I've had problems with Swing with JDK 7/8 when my second monitor's top `y` coordinate was negative relative to my first one.

Comment: That is a clue! I rearranged the monitors into a side-by-side, rather than top-bottom arrangement and I can drag the window across the screens as expected! An interesting aspect of the top-bottom arrangement is that once I attempt to drag the window to another desktop, the window is gone for good. I can enter Mission Control and grab the window and move it to the other (original) desktop, but it also "sinks" off screen. I wonder if there's a work-around for this...

Comment: Having the same issue - yworks yed (a regular java app) will launch on my laptop's display, but when I try to drag it to an external monitor, POOF!  Gone.  Driving me nuts.

Comment: Check that the video driver and the JRE are up to date. It is possible to have a current JDK, but an old JRE. Maybe you can try to set opengl acceleration -Dsun.java2d.opengl=true See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html#opengl

Comment: Maybe you can use `Component.getLocationOnScreen()` on one of your components, and regularly output the location to `System.out`? Might make it easier to determine what Swing thinks the position on the secondary screen is...

Comment: Here is a guess: there are 2 ways of Arranging two monitors (A = 1st, B = second monitor): AB and BA. If you have configuration BA, could it be that the coordinates become negative? So if you change your arrangement to AB it could work.

Comment: Yeah, logging `Component.getLocationOnScreen` would be useful. You could write a little event listener to do it in response to every Window move/resize/visibility event. And you can use the Java `GraphicsDevice`/`GraphicsConfiguration` API to figure out what Java's view of the arrangement of screens is.

Comment: Also, are any of your displays Retina displays?

Comment: Can you try setting a minimum size for the frame - frame.setMinimumSize( Dimension d )?

Answer (score 2):

Step: Before frame.setVisible(true); you can add below two line of code and then test again.

frame.setLocation(500, 500);
frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Go to System Preferences > Displays > Arrangement
2. Align the two rectangles perfectly
3. See if it works
4. If not, change the order of the 2 rectangles (and the monitors or plug them in differently)

Hope this helps, but I'm not sure if it is the solution.